# How to send specific UITableView row to specific ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have 3 `ViewControllers` and a table view with 3 items.

How can i send each `tableview` row to different `viewcontroller`?

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var data: [String] = ["Go to First VC", "Go to Second VC", "Go to Third VC"]

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Table configurations
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
}
```

My guess is to apply a `performSegue()` in `didSelectRowAt` function but i don't know how to reference the particular row.

Comment: You are almost there, You could use `indexPath.row` property to identify which cell clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method just check for indexpath.row

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    // go to first viewController
 } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    // go to Second viewController
 } else if indexPath.row == 0 {
    // go to Third viewController
 }
```

Comment: so did you make it ?

Comment: Umair, can you help me with something else? Can i call PrepareForSegue() inside this didSelectRowAtIndexPath if in order to pass different objects to different ViewControllers?

Comment: read [This](http://mhorga.org/2015/07/11/passing-data-between-viewcontrollers.html)

Answer (score 0):

first in tableviews did select method you need to identify indexPath.row
here indexpath contains section and row so you need to check row for segue.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        //segue first view controller
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        //segue second view controller
    }
    else {
        //segue last(third) view controller
    }
}
```

hope this will help you.